# Do these colors fit in the logo?

Tags: logo, images

In this logo that I am making, I would like you to tell me if it looks professional, or if it needs to be improved.
[image]

As you can see, it has a deep blue color around the face, and a red almost orange color on the nose.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Colour choice is subjective, and so too is appreciation of a logo. In my personal opinion, I'm not sure how the logo fits with the name of the business. I can't quite work out the connection between the clown face and craft. Also I feel the logo is far too big in relation to the text underneath.  But these are just opinions.

Comment: @BillyKerr  Craft sounds also like it could be seen as a skill to deceive others. A harmless clown could be quite a good disguise.

Comment: @user287001 - I think it's fairly obvious that it's some kind of arts and crafts company, although the OP has failed to give any real details. I don't think it has anything to do with being deceptive. Although that is one meaning of the word "craft" it would be very rare to use it in that context, especially in a company name. It wouldn't really make any sense to a native English speaker.

Answer (score 0):

I personally feel there should be good contrast between *colors*. If you're using 2 colors adjacent to each other, you might lose the purpose of it if it doesn't have much contrast.

For example, The black and blue colors are kind of mixing. If it would be possible, I would make the blue a bit brighter like this (see image).

However, I will also try to adjust the blue color itself so it doesn't look bad to me, overall in logo. I would experiment with many blue colors. Right now, on my laptop, the following update blue color looks okay to me, but on my phone it looks *very bad to me* (contrast is improved though). So which blue to choose, is totally up to you and requirements.

[image]

A little more bright:

[image]

Other than that, it seems fine to me.

My personal opinions about logo itself:

1. The copyright symbol looks misplaced
2. The text is a bit too close to the main artwork
3. I will definitely experiment different blue colors